# Unable to display responsiv image using ImgLiquid

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an issue trying to use [ImgLiquid](https://github.com/karacas/imgLiquid) ; I don't get why but when I launch it the image are not showing anymore.
I've tried to add directly the code into my page but this is not changing anything.

Could it be a priority problem or a conflict problem ?

It's strange because the plugin seems to load properly since I've got no consol issues and a change in my display.

Here is the before after : [image]

And this is how I've "hardcoded it". Maybe is it there where I'm doign it wrong ?

[image]

How I lunch the function :

```
$(function() {

    $(".imgLiquidFill").imgLiquid({
        fill: true,
        horizontalAlign: "center",
        verticalAlign: "top"
    });

});
```

And this is the style I saw; does it seems normale to you.. 
(`display:none` and `visibility:hidden`)

[image]

### EDIT AND ANSWER :

So for anyone who encounter this problem later : here is the solution and where does the problem came from (what I got of it).

**The image *was displaying* but; since the image is displayed as a background image, it was the div which has no height who wasn't.** I had to specify an height to the the box so it can be displayed properly. For now on I've just set an height of `WTVpx`.

Later I'll fix it by getting the height of the bigger div (in green and set it has the height of my block with jQuery.

Hope this can help someone one day.

Comment: The image in the JsFiddle was not found. Try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g1esymnk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Duplicate of my post for better visibility

So for anyone who encounter this problem later : here is the solution and where does the problem came from (what I got of it).

The image was displaying but; since the image is displayed as a background image, it was the div which has no height who wasn't. I had to specify an height to the the box so it can be displayed properly. For now on I've just set an height of WTVpx.

Later I'll fix it by getting the height of the bigger div (in green and set it has the height of my block with jQuery.

Hope this can help someone one day.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the images no longer exist.  you should see errors/404's in your console.

try going to http://www.juegostoystory.net/files/image/2010_Toy_Story_3_USLC12_Woody.jpg in your browser, the image is gone, so it wont show in the page when using the plugin.

That's why the fiddle doesnt work. as I cant see your code I can only assume you are using the same images

Comment: Yeah i've figure that out; But no, in my page I'm using the same image as before... I've edited my code with a bunch of precision.

Comment: "I've edited my code with a bunch of precision" where? have you edited the plugin??

Comment: Just did it sry I didnt expected you to be this quick

Comment: Ok It was a problem of box size ; The box showed up to be 0px of width I don't know why.. Anyway it's ok for now on :)

Comment: glad you managed to sort it. might be a good idea to update the question to help others who might have the same problem